# Convergence of the Expected value

Tags: probability, analysis

In my lecture Notes was mentioned that, given a random variable X with density f, a uniform continuous function g and if $(X_n)$ is a discrete  approximation of X. Then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb E[g(X_n)]=\mathbb E[g(X)]$

Now I am trying to understand why.
I think that g being uniformly continuous should be the crucial part, but i can't figure out why also I don't see why the density f is needed.

Edit:
$X_n:=a^{-n}\lceil a^n X \rceil$, and I am assuming that E[g(X)] exists

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly  is 'discerte approximation of $X$'? Why do the expecations exist?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy discrete approximation means that for a $\in \mathbb{N} X_n:=a^{(-n)}\lceil a^n X \rceil$

Comment: If $X$ is a r.v. with density and $g$ is uniformly continuous there is no reason why $Eg(X)$ exists. [Ex. Take $g(x)=x$ and let $X$ have Cauchy distribution].  So the question is not formulated properly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are right, it should actually be assuming that $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]$ exists ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined $X_n$ as $a^{-n}[a^{n}X]$ in your comment. I will assume that $a>1$ and $Eg(X)$ exists.

Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)| <\epsilon$ if $|x-y| <\delta$. Note that $X-\frac 1 {a^{n}} <X_n \leq X$ (by definition of the greatest integer function).
If $n$ is so large that $\frac  1{a^{n}} <\delta$ then $|g(X_n)-g(X)| <\epsilon$ do $|Eg(X_n)-Eg(X)| \leq \epsilon$. This proves the result.

You are right about the density part. This result has nothing to do with the existence of the density.

Comment: thank you very much